# How to find the RestController template that matches a given URI in spring?

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin

Given a input URI string how to find the RestController template that matches this?

For example, given an input URI - `/users/1` it should match to `/users/{id}`

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using `RequestMappingHandlerMapping`

Get a list of all path patterns that's configured using the RestController.

Note: This will not return paths that have not been configured using RestController

```kotlin
 private fun getAllPathPatterns(): List<PathPattern> {
     val patterns: MutableList<PathPattern> = mutableListOf()
     requestMappingHandlerMapping.handlerMethods.forEach {
         (mapping, _) ->
         patterns.addAll(mapping.patternsCondition.patterns)
     }
     return patterns
 }
```

Map the URI to it's corresponding path pattern that was configured using RestController. If there's no such path pattern return "unknown"

```
 private fun normaliseUri(uri: String): String {
     val uriPath = PathContainer.parsePath(uri)
     val pathPatterns = getAllPathPatterns()
     val matchingPattern = pathPatterns.find { pathPattern -> pathPattern.matches(uriPath) } ?: return "unknown"
     return matchingPattern.patternString
 }
```